# search in a list .contains return false

Tags: flutter

I have a list of this model `List<AnimeModel> animeModels=[];`

```
AnimeModel animeModel=AnimeModel(id: "id", name: "name", image: "image");
```

after adding this model to the list when I do this **it returns false why** ?

```
if(animeModels.contains(animeModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `AnimeModel` properly implement `==` and `hashCode`? My guess is that it does not and that's why. Unless you're initializing `const` instances, Dart does object equality based on identity unless those methods are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet may help you understand your problem.

```
  var animemodel = AnimeModel(id: "0", name: "One", image: "img");
  var animemodel2 = AnimeModel(id: "2", name: "Two", image: "Img2");
  var list = [animemodel, animemodel2];
  
  print("${list.contains(animemodel)}"); //Will return True
  
  var animemodel3 = AnimeModel(id: "0", name: "One", image: "img");
  
  print("${list.contains(animemodel3)}"); //Will return False
```

If you want animemodel3 to return `true`, you should override those two methods in your AnimeModel class :

```
  bool operator ==(o) => o is AnimeModel && name == o.name && id == o.id;
  int get hashCode => hash2(id.hashCode, name.hashCode);
```

Comment: Object.hash() is the preferred hashing method now I believe

Comment: That's what I am doing and it's not working